# Adding a file browser button to a MS Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, file-browser

I'd like to add a "Browse" button to an MS Access 2007 form that will bring up a standard Windows file browser (as a modal window) and allow the user to select a directory. When the user OKs out of that browser, the path the the selected directory should be written to a text box in the Access form.

What's the best way to do this? Is there a native Access way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a function which uses `Application.FileDialog`.  The `FileDialog` is modal.

This function will return the user's folder selection if they made one, or an empty string if they clicked cancel on the `FileDialog`.

```vb
Public Function FolderSelection() As String
    Dim objFD As Object
    Dim strOut As String

    strOut = vbNullString
    'msoFileDialogFolderPicker = 4
    Set objFD = Application.FileDialog(4)
    If objFD.Show = -1 Then
        strOut = objFD.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    Set objFD = Nothing
    FolderSelection = strOut
End Function
```

I think you can use that function in your command button's click event.

```vb
Dim strChoice As String
strChoice = FolderSelection
If Len(strChoice) > 0 Then
    Me.TextBoxName = strChoice
Else
    ' what should happen if user cancelled selection?
End If
```

If you're concerned that Microsoft may remove the `FileDialog` object from Office someday, you can use the Windows API method instead: [BrowseFolder Dialog](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0002.htm).

Comment: I always recommend using the Windows API instead, as I don't trust MS to not remove the FileDialog object from Office someday, as they removed the FileSearch object from Office 2007.