# Access - Hyperlinks Aren't Linking

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, vba, transform

I have a form with a user created function (See here for function:  [Adding a file browser button to a MS Access form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203852/adding-a-file-browser-button-to-a-ms-access-form)) to pull a folder path name into a text box.

Ideally, I want this text to become a hyperlink that can be opened from a query.  However, for all records I have added from the form the hyperlink is not working.  I looked in "Edit Hyperlink" for the records and there is no address.  Also, I had manually entered some records in before I had made the form and their hyperlinks worked just fine by pasting the folder path name into the cell, and still work now.

I think the issue is that the function I am using returns a plain string, is there any way to transform it into a working hyperlink once it is in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly speaking, a functional Access Hyperlink field value is a string which includes `#` characters between the "hyperlink parts".  (See Access' *Application.HyperlinkPart Method* help topic.)

For example, this `DLookup` returns the stored value for a link which is displayed as *AccessApps* and which links to my *C:\Users\hans\AccessApps* folder.

```vb
? DLookup("url", "tblFoo", "id=1")
AccessApps#C:\Users\hans\AccessApps#
```

However, if I store only the string which contains the folder path ...

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblFoo " & _
    "SET url='C:\Users\hans\AccessApps' " & _
    "WHERE id=4"
```

... the string does get stored ...

```vb
? DLookup("url", "tblFoo", "id=4")
C:\Users\hans\AccessApps
```

... but since it doesn't include `#` characters, Access doesn't treat it as a clickable hyperlink.  It's just text which *looks* like a link, but clicking it does nothing.

Meanwhile it seems you're using a function named `FolderSelection()` to select a folder path string.  If you want to store the function's return value as a hyperlink, you can include `#` characters before and after.

```vb
"#" & FolderSelection() & "#"
```

If you want the folder path as the link but have it displayed as something else, put the display part before the first `#`.

```vb
"Click Me!#" & FolderSelection() & "#"
```

Comment: Aha! *That's* what those `#` thingies in Hyperlink fields are all about. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, it works exactly how I wanted it to!  For anyone interested, here is the edited code:

```
Private Sub Command26_Click()
Dim strChoice As String
strChoice = FolderSelection
If Len(strChoice) > 0 Then
    Me.Photo_Location = "#" & strChoice & "#"
    ' the "#" & additions around strChoice above complete the hyperlink
Else
    ' what should happen if user cancelled selection?
End If
End Sub
```

I guess the `#` character could have been placed somewhere else, but I am a new to this!