# Inserting images in Access database as hyperlink

Tags: image, ms-access, hyperlink, vba

I'm trying to insert an image path into an Access database. I have a hyperlink field named `logo`, and I'm using this code to browse for images:

```
Dim dialog As FileDialog
Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With dialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select A File To Use As A Logo"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png"
    .ButtonName = "Use This File"
    If .Show = True Then
        Me.im1 = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End If
End With
```

`im1` is an unbound textbox used to view the path. The problem is that it's displaying the file path as text, not as a hyperlink. I'd like to display the file name as a hyperlink in my form in `im1`. Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access - Hyperlinks Aren't Linking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581485/access-hyperlinks-arent-linking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text is text. If you want something to show up as a hyperlink you need to tell your textbox that's what it's doing. It can't guess.

im1.IsHyperlink=True

*However*, The easier thing to do is probably to use a Label instead of a textbox. Set the `.HyperlinkAddress` property to your link address