# Hyperlink "deactivated" after VBA on textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been using VBA and available modules to integrate the browse for directory and browse for file functionalities in two different MS Access projects. Here are the example files where I took the functionalities from:

**Browse to folder:** http://www.lebans.com/callbackbrowser.htm

**Browse to file:** http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=97787

In both my .mdb projects, I have tried to browse for a file/folder, then output the address to a hyperlink textbox, linked to a hyperlink field in a table.

It has mostly worked, but unfortunately, with both these functionalities, the hyperlink stops working... The output to the textbox and to the table seems perfect, but when I click on the hyperlink, it does not take me to Windows Explorer.

To make the hyperlink work, I have to double click on the textbox, (which then lets me edit the field) remove the last letter, then type it back again, and tab out. Then, when I click, Windows Explorer opens normally, as a hyperlink should.

What is the solution? I've already tried:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

Without success...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question on stackoverflow:

[Access - Hyperlinks Aren't Linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581485/access-hyperlinks-arent-linking)

Turns out you need to concatenate #'s before and after the hyperlink address for it to work properly as a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to open an explorer window for a specified directory set in the textbox?

If so, you'll need to use the textbox on-click event, something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Shell "C:\windows\explorer.exe """ & TextBox1.Value & "", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Or, you can use the double-click event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Shell "C:\windows\explorer.exe """ & TextBox1.Value & "", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

By the way, I could only test this in Excel - I don't have Access installed, but it should be the same.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to not use code for this, as this functionality should work without additional code... After I hit backspace, and retype the letter I erased, it opens an Explorer window, even when viewing the table directly and clicking on the link. However, this is a good alternative, if I cannot find a more direct solution. Thank you!