# How do I get a hyperlink to show up in a form in microsoft access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, hyperlink, vba

THERE ARE TWO PARTS TO THIS QUESTION:

Part 1: Right now I have a form that will upload, insert, and delete from the table. I would like to have the last textbox link to a hyperlink.

Using this code works for hyperlinks (see below and see this: [Access - Hyperlinks Aren't Linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581485/access-hyperlinks-arent-linking)), but now I need to change the text to say something like "Open attachment" instead of the file location. For buttons, I know this is done by using ".Caption" but what is the code to change the text for a textbox and to keep the hyperlink I just inserted?

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = " Please select file"
        If .Show = True Then
            Selectfile = .SelectedItems(1)
            Me.txtHyperlink = "#" & Selectfile & "#"
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set fd = Nothing
 End With
```

Part 2: Whenever I insert the file path, the file also opens in another window. I want this to stop and to just link to the file and change the text box to say "Attachment", but also keep the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1: Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html
A hyperlink entry contains three parts separated by pound signs (#). The template is:
    display text # file name # any reference within the file

```
Me.txtHyperlink = "Open Attachment#" & Selectfile & "#"
```

Textbox IsHyperlink property must be set to Yes.

Part 2: don't really understand the issue.
What kind of files are you opening? What kind of window opens? Might need to use FollowHyperlink - review http://allenbrowne.com/func-GoHyperlink.html
I have encountered situation where FollowHyperlink would not work and so used Shell method:

```
Dim wsShell As Object  
Set wsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
wsShell.Run Chr(34) & Me.tbxLink & Chr(34)
```

Comment: There we go!! I wasn't sure of the formatting with the display text going inside of the quotes!